# python scrape page + next page loop from url or element button

Tags: python, selenium

It just prints the first page does not go and prints the other page
where is the problem?
I'm new to Python

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

for num in range(1,6):     #Number of pages plus one
    url = (f'https://test.com/%D9%84-%8%B6/{num}')
    html = urlopen(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
```

Comment: did you manually check the first  URL in browser?

Comment: yeah it print page number 1 only .

Answer (score 0):

You want to be doing something like so:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for num in range(1, 6):  # Number of pages plus one
    url = f"https://google.com/{num}"
    r = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    print(bs)
```

`urllib.request import urlopen` is not needed for this.

---

Regarding the comments below, here is getting the title of my [website](https://self.st) with `BeautifulSoup`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://self.st"  # You would have your number here.
r = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

title = bs.find("div", {"class": "title"})

print(title)
print(title.text)
```

Outputs:

```
<div class="title">felipe faria</div>
felipe faria
```

[image]

Comment: Hi
Your Method worked but when I modified the code

```python

for num in range (1, 6): # Number of pages plus one
url = f "https://test.com/%D9%{num}"

r = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})

for image in images: 
    print(image['src'].split('/')[-1].split('_')[0])

bs = BeautifulSoup (html, 'html.parser')
NameError: name 'html' is not defined
```

^
output problem in the console
sorry am new it python :(

Comment: No worries, but try to figure it out -- the interpreter probably told you where that `html` is at that is not working... _hint, hint_: `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`. That should be `r.text`, not `html` as given by the code above.

Comment: i fix it now i get another problem :(

in the console 

looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
  ' that document to Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup

Comment: What if switched: BeautifulSoup  To: Selenium?
I think it will be easier + click on the page on the specified 

element Example:
"Pagebtn"
This Element

https://prnt.sc/ptebfe

Comment: Selenium would be a bit overkill, I believe. You are most likely not doing `r.text` and instead just `r` in the line `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`; make sure you are doing `BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')`. Notice how it says "You should probably use an HTTP client like **requests**..."

Comment: Also, I don't mean to be rude, but _Google it_. The reality is, programming is 60%-70% research, and only 40%-30% programming. If you pasted that exact error on Google you would've seen hundreds of results of people asking the same thing.

Comment: @Mydoo Added example of extracting a `div` from my own personal website so you can see how `BeautifulSoup` + `requests` works.